# Processing a database cursor in Haskell

Tags: database, haskell, cursor

In a related [Scala question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786054/functionally-processing-a-database-cursor-in-scala), I asked the following:

When I need to read millions of database rows from a PostgreSQL database using the JDBC driver, I always use a cursor, otherwise I will get an OutOfMemoryError. Here is the pattern (pseudocode) that I use:

```
begin transaction
execute("declare cursor...")
while (true) {
  boolean processedSomeRows = false
  resultSet = executeQuery("fetch forward...")
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    processedSomeRows = true
    ...
  }
  if (!processedSomeRows) break
}
close cursor
commit
```

How can this be done in idiomatic Haskell?

Comment: Have you tried lazily fetching the rows with HDBC or its likes and making sure they are consumed nicely? Does this cause a memory problem?

Comment: I have not actually tried this in Haskell. I am looking for a pattern for processing an outer loop that depends on the processing in an inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is quite new concept for dealing with streams like sql cursor: [iteratees](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/Iteratee/IterateeM.hs), or [enumerator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator), or [conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit). For example, in terms of the conduit library, from [Persistent Book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent-raw-sql-133):

```
runResourceT $ withStmt "declare cursor..." []
    $$ mapM_ doSomethingWithSingleResult
```

`withStmt "declare cursor..." []` creates `source` with rows, `mapM_ doSomethingWithSingleResult`  creates `sink` for process single rows, and `$$` connects `source` with `sink`.