# Scala idiomatic streaming generators for external (potentially unbounded) IO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, web-scraping, generator

I have two use cases 1) traverse a database cursor 2) implement a framework for data scraping similar to Python's Scrapy. I'd simply like to write stuff using a for loop and yields.

My two questions are:

1) **The important one:** How do I implement generators for IO so that it retrieves stuff an element at a time, and it looks somewhat like a Python generator. The Scala Stream examples are focused on mathematical problems, and the "How do I implement a Python generator" ones don't go into enough detail :D

2) The signature of the generator will be implemented as functions returning only single entities as well as streams. How do I do this without having to explicitly define a return as a single-value Sequence?

Example (from my prototyping):

```
abstract class Expression
case class Visit(val url: String) extends Expression
case class SelectMultiple(selector: String, 
    List[(Element)=>ExpressionResult]) extends Expression
```

Visit will most likely return a single result, whereas `SelectMultiple` will spit out Urls, and extracted items to be written out to disk.

With:

```
abstract class ExpressionResult
case class ExtractedEntity(val entity: Entity) extends ExpressionResult
case class ExtractedRequest(val url: String) extends ExpressionResult
case class Continue() extends ExpressionResult
case class Ignore() extends ExpressionResult
```

I have :

```
case class Visit(url:String, andDo: ScrapeExpression) extends ScrapeExpression{
  override def execute : ExpressionResult = {
    val doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
    andDo.element = doc
    println( "visiting")
    andDo.execute
    Continue()
  }
}
```

But I am having to change the signature of execute to `Seq[ExpressionResult]` for `SelectMultiple`

P.s., the above prototype shows the case classes with executors, I will move the logic external to the expression tree after I figure out how to write the generators.

**Possibly related**

[How to implement lazy sequence (iterable) in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511214/how-to-implement-lazy-sequence-iterable-in-scala)

[Stream vs Views vs Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159000/stream-vs-views-vs-iterators)

[Functionally processing a database cursor in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786054/functionally-processing-a-database-cursor-in-scala)

[Treating an SQL ResultSet like a Scala Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636545/treating-an-sql-resultset-like-a-scala-stream)

**Train of thought:**

*I have a feeling modelling an Iterator is probably my best bet in this case, but I have not looked into how they fit into for expressions yet. But will the traits and templates for iterators in library interop well with a for expression, and even if they do, will they cover the streaming use-case?*

*Should I be writing the io code in Java (shoot me now :~( ) ?*

Comment: Have a look at `itretees`